# create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Django rest framework,. How to slove it?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django restframework I want to register a new student to school but it does not work. I have tried many solutions . what I got is:create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given when I try to post. I am not sure if my code in the viewset correct. Can someone help me?

```
 In my serializers.py:
 class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ['first_name']


class SchoolSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
is_existing_student = = serializers.BooleanField()
student = StudentSerializer(many=True)

 class Meta:
    model = School
    fields = ['is_existing_student', 'name', 'city', 'street', 'student']

  def create(self, **validated_data):
    student_data = validated_data.pop('student')
    school_instance = School.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for student_data in student_data:
        Student.objects.create(school_instance=school_instance, **student_data)
    return school_instance
```

In my views.py:

```
  class SchoolViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, 
  ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):

      serializer_class = SchoolSerializer
      queryset = School.objects.all()

      @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
      def school(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          school = self.get_object()
          if serializer.is_valid():
             School.create(school=school, name='name', street='street', city='city', 
                           student='student')
             school.save()
          else:
             return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

In my url:

```
  router.register(r'register', SchoolViewSet)
```

Comment: The `student='student'` look quite strange. Your `.create(...)` method expects an iterable of dictionaries, not a string.

Comment: Do you mean it should be student=**student_data?-@WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In create function, you should not unpack validated_data. So create function definition should look like this

```python
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
 is_existing_student = = serializers.BooleanField()
 student = StudentSerializer(many=True)

 class Meta:
    model = School
    fields = ['is_existing_student', 'name', 'city', 'street', 'student']

  def create(self, validated_data):
    student_data = validated_data.pop('student')
    school_instance = School.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for student_data in student_data:
        Student.objects.create(school_instance=school_instance, **student_data)
    return school_instance
```

Also in the view part you duplicate School object creation. Serializer is responsible for creating school instance already

```python
  class SchoolViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, 
  ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):

      serializer_class = SchoolSerializer
      queryset = School.objects.all()

      @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
      def school(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          school_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
          if school_serializer.is_valid():
             school_serializer.save()
          else:
             return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: It works, it posted only the school fields but not the student, and I got the following typeError: django.db.models.manager.BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str- @kuba Ronkiewicz